# opening a file from files directory android

Tags: android

Hi i have saved a file from a url to my files directory. And set a broadcast recover to detect when the download has completed to then fire an action_view intent to choose which app to open it in. which all works fine but when i choose another application it can't display the file. if i select the file form the notification centre it opens up fine so it definitely gets download loaded into the files directory but no idea why it would load when opened from my application.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                            request.setTitle(filename);
                            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            }

                            ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
                            final String filePath = c.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/";
                            Log.v("Search", "filePath = " + filePath);
                            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getBaseContext(), filePath, filename);

                            // get download service and enqueue file
                            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            manager.enqueue(request);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {


                                @Override
                                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                                    String path = getFilesDir().getPath() +"/" + filename;
                                    File f = new File(path); 
                                    Log.v("Search", "path = " + path);
                                    String fileExt = Global.getFileExt(filename);
                                    MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

                                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                                    String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt);
                                    newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), mimeType);
                                    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    try {
                                        context.startActivity(newIntent);
                                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "No handler for this type of file.", 4000).show();
                                    }
                                }


                            };

                            registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

                        }
```